# How can I manipulate pixels in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Let me explain what I want to achieve..

I'm building something just for fun and as a learning experiment similar to

www.milliondollarhomepage.com

Except, I want to use canvas and/or Fabric.js to achieve the same thing. How would I go about manipulating each pixel in a canvas?

Scenario:

- I want to offer a 1000 pixels up for grabs.
- User can choose an image and where it should go on the canvas
- Image can be resized according to how many pixels the user wants and deducted from the overall remaining pixels.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: This seem similar to fabricjs demo http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/, you can adjust individual pixels on the canvas but it is a lot more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in the HTML5 canvas api for manipulating individual pixels is

```
context.getImageData(x,y,width,height);
```

for example

```
var map = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

This returns a massive array that contains in repeating order:

```
[red,green,blue,alpha,red,green,blue,alpha...]
```

Every `4` numbers represent the red, green, blue, and alpha channels for every single pixel on the chosen area, left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

The values for each of these numbers is an integer ranging from `0 - 255`.

To loop through every pixel and drop their `red` and `blue` channels, thus turning the image green, for example

```
//assume map variable from earlier

for(var i = 0; i < map.data.length; i+=4){
    map.data[i] = 0; // drop red to 0
    map.data[i+2] = 0; // drop blue to 0
}
context.putImageData(map,0,0);
```

[See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/3CWz5/)

Note that this procedure can only be done on a server, and without images from other domains "contaminating" the canvas. If these requirements are not met, a security error DOM exception will be thrown.

Comment: A note on the order of the channels for each pixel in the `map` array: this order is what's called [Big Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_endian). Most structures in computing, however (e.g. http packets, most low-level graphical APIs), use Little Endian. An example of this is interfacing with the Linux Framebuffer in a C program. When mapped (assuming 32-bit color), the order of each channel is something like: `b,g,r,a,b,g,r,a,b,g,r,a,...`. Thus, to access a given red channel, it would be `*(map + location + 2)` (or `map[location + 2]`) where `location` represents a pixel's index.